# "Something is scheduled starting AS OF tomorrow". Is this the correct usage?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

"Something is scheduled starting AS OF tomorrow". Is this the correct usage? I do not like the sound of it. What would a native speaker use in this situation?

Thank you.

Comment: Rephrasing it to "[Something] is scheduled to start (as of) [some date]." is more natural. I think *as of* is unnecessary, and if you used *starting*, it would sound less natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Something is scheduled starting AS OF tomorrow

Is an odd one to say, normally you are more specific with your words, for example you would say "starting as of 3pm" but tomorrow is very vague. It is however, still valid.

"starting as of" is normally used to specifically schedule, to say something starts tomorrow you normally just say "it is tomorrow" or "it starts tomorrow" or even "it will start tomorrow".

Sometimes "starting as of" is used to convey an emotion of drama. A good example of this is a competition.

Is the same as saying:

> As of tomorrow something will have started

Comment: Maybe this will help: which are scheduled starting as of tomorrow in Portuguese and German languages

Comment: @Oscar does this relate to lessons? If it relates to a static time that is assumed to be known then it is not vague

Comment: Yes, this relates to lessons. Webinars to be exact.

Comment: @Oscar then it is quite valid indeed :)

Comment: Please let me know the meaning of: “the discounts are available as of tomorrow”.

Comment: @LucianSava I don't think that would be vague either since a store brings out discounts and you normally know the opening times of a store. This is a very strange bit of English but it relies upon whether or not the audience understands that tomorrow really means, for example, 9am

Comment: Reason for the downvote? He asked what a native speaker would say; he got what a native speaker would say

Comment: I don’t see any reason to not upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[As of](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20of) is a correct expression, has a temporal meaning and expresses the date (time) when an event starts or ends.

In your context there’s no ambiguity, as the words “starting” and “tomorrow” are used.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you are saying that I can leave the sentence as it is?
In what cases I would not use the words "as of"?

Comment: @Oscar, definitely!

Comment: Thank you! I will wait a couple of hours before I mark your answer as the best.